# What is the difference between using a polynomial object and np.polyval to evaluate a polynomial in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I am working with polynomials in NumPy and I am wondering about the difference between using a polynomial object and the np.polyval function to evaluate a polynomial at a specific value. For example, what is the difference between these two code snippets:

```
equation = np.poly1d(coeff_list)
x = equation(z)
```

```
x = (np.polyval(equation, z))
```

Here, the equation is a polynomial object obtained by using the np.poly1d function and z is the value at which we want to evaluate the polynomial. Both code snippets will give me the same result, but I am curious about the underlying differences.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two approaches? Is one approach preferred over the other in certain situations? Thanks!

Comment: np.polyval is deprecated.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, It is deprecated, but what is the new or advantage in the polynomial object method?

Comment: It's what the authors of numpy want you to use.  It means that np.polyval may disappear.  If it had any advantages (which I doubt), the authors of numpy did not consider it worthwhile to maintain.  They thought that evaluating a polynomial at a point was an intrinsic part of being the polynomial, and therefore should be a method that was part of the polynomial.  Don't overthink this.

Comment: you can read the source code for `polyval`

Comment: @FrankYellin, that note about `polyval` being old applies to `poly1d` as well.  And it doesn't actually threaten deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

`poly1d` is a class, so `eq` is an instance of that class:

```
In [8]: eq = np.poly1d([1,2,3])

In [9]: type(eq)
Out[9]: numpy.poly1d
```

`eq` has a `__call__` method (it's a `callable`), so can be used as:

```
In [10]: eq(np.arange(5))
Out[10]: array([ 3,  6, 11, 18, 27])
```

`polyval` is a function, whose code is readily readable from the doc page:

Calling it with a `poly1d` instance is the same as calling it with the same list of coefficients (plus a 0):

```
In [11]: np.polyval(eq, np.arange(5))
Out[11]: array([ 3,  6, 11, 18, 27])

In [12]: np.polyval([0,1,2,3], np.arange(5))
Out[12]: array([ 3,  6, 11, 18, 27])
```

That's because if you iterate on `eq` you get its coefficients:

```
In [13]: list(eq)
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]
```

I can't offhand find the code for `poly1d`; but I suspect it's fairly straight forward python.  It may even evaluate the polynomial in the same way as `polyval`.  Direct use of `eq(x)` is slightly faster, but that may more the result of levels of function calls than real evaluation differences.

The note about  "`numpy.polynomial` is preferred" applies to both `polyval` and `poly1d`.  It may be preferred if you want to do fancy stuff with polynomials, or more general types, but for simple evaluation with a list of coefficients, I don't see much advantage.

Here's the code for `polyval`:

```
def polyval(p, x):
    p = NX.asarray(p)
    if isinstance(x, poly1d):
        y = 0
    else:
        x = NX.asanyarray(x)
        y = NX.zeros_like(x)
    for pv in p:
        y = y * x + pv
    return y
```

### edit

The `call` method of `poly1d` is actually a call to `polyval`:

```
def __call__(self, val):
    return polyval(self.coeffs, val)
```

This is all in the `np.lib.polynomial.py` file